# sql server select distinct with ID

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct

I want to write a select distinct statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO  Table2(ID, ColA, ColB, ColC) 
SELECT DISTINCT ID,ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM Table1
```

What happens now is that all data is copied because of the ID field. Can i create an insert into statement with a select distinct query which selects different data from ColA,ColB,ColC, but also inserts the ID field into Table2 without using it for the Select distinct query?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CTE`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as
(
    select rn = row_number() over
    (
        partition by cola,colb,colc
        order by id
    ),*
    from Table1
)
insert into Table2(id,cola,colb,colc)
select id,cola,colb,colc
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50bde/1)

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make ID field of your table2 as primary key or identity column and then using a GROUP BY you can try this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(ColA, ColB, ColC) 
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC FROM Table1
GROUP BY ColA, ColB, ColC
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using `Identity` function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS id,
                    ColA,
                    ColB,
                    ColC
    INTO   Table2
    FROM   Table1
```

**Note :** The `IDENTITY` function can only be used when the `SELECT` statement has an `INTO` clause. You cannot use this in `Insert ..into`